# Animating between ARAnchor orientations

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, arimageanchor

I have an app that is using `ARImageAnchor`s to detect images with the camera. I've noticed that although the scene node's position in 3d space updates in real-time, the orientation (xyz rotation) of the node can take seconds to update. Any attached scene nodes "snap" to the new orientation as it updates.

Is there a way to animate between the changing anchor orientations to make the transitions smoother?

My setup is simple, I'm using `renderer(didAdd:for:)` to add a plane to the supplied node.

Comment: If you keep a reference to the anchor and use `renderer(_ renderer:didUpdate:for:)` will you get new information for that anchor?

Comment: Yes, but by that time the geometry is already reflecting the new orientation on the screen making it too late to animate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer necessary with ARKit 2.0. Simply use ARKit 2.0's image tracking instead of image recognition.